# How does inheritance behave when a style has both a parent attribute and a dotted name?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

According to the Android API Guide [Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), a style can inherit from another in two different ways:

- It can have a `parent` attribute:

  > The `parent` attribute in the `<style>` element lets you specify a style from which your style should inherit attributes. You can use this to inherit attributes from an existing style and define only the attributes that you want to change or add.
- It can have a dotted name, as long as the style being inherited from is one "you've defined yourself":

  > If you want to inherit from styles that you've defined yourself, you don't have to use the `parent`. Instead, you can use dot notation by prefixing the name of the style you want to inherit to the name of your new style, separated by a period.

What happens if a `<style>` has both a parent and a dotted name? For example, if I have:

```
 <style name="Foo.Bar.Baz" parent="Pen.Pinapple.Apple.Pen">
```

Does `Foo.Bar.Baz` inherit from both `Foo.Bar` and `Pen.Pinapple.Apple.Pen`? If an attribute is set in both `Foo.Bar` and `Pen.Pinapple.Apple.Pen`, which value will it get in `Foo.Bar.Baz`? What about other cases, like an attribute being set in `Pen.Pineapple` but also being set in the `parent` of `Foo.Bar`? Exactly what are the cascading rules, and where are they documented?

Comment: You'll find this a lot in the platform sdk (e.g `styles_material.xml`), twisted my head finding what's being in effective...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you specify both, the `parent` attribute completely overrules the "dotted parent" (i.e., anything defined in the dotted parent is ignored).

In this example, `MyStyle2.SubStyle` will inherit the text color attribute from `MyStyle1` and completely ignore the text size attribute from `MyStyle2`:

```
<style name="MyStyle1">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00f</item>
</style>

<style name="MyStyle2">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyStyle2.SubStyle" parent="MyStyle1">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, than answers a specific case, but what is the general rule? What happens if the attr is set in MyStyle2 but not in MyStyle1? Does setting the parent man the "dotted parent" is completely ignored, or does the explicit parent just take precedence?

Comment: "What happens if the attr is set in MyStyle2 but not in MyStyle1?" That exact scenario is covered in my answer. `android:textStyle` from `MyStyle2` is completely ignored. Setting the `parent` attr means that the "dotted parent" is completely ignored (as are all of _that_ style's parents).

Comment: Whoops! Yes, I misread your example -- I thought both MyStyle1 and MyStyle2 were setting the same attr, and so I wasn't sure what "wins" meant. Sorry about that.

Comment: So it looks like a style has at most one parent, and the dotted name is only used to pick a parent when the parent attribute is not specified.

Comment: That is my understanding as well, though I'm not aware of any documentation that states this explicitly.

Comment: By the way, thanks for alerting me to the fact that opening quick docs on a style reference actually shows all of the attrs in the style and how they're set. That certainly makes it easier to figure out what's going on.